# What kind of compound for taping with paper tape?

Tags: drywall

I’ve got a ton of EasySand 45 left over from a project, but everything online I can find ways to use a taping compound. But what is that? Should I be using All Purpose or some mix of All Purpose with EasySand?

Would be all hot mud, not premixed. I use premixed Plus3 for topping.

Comment: If you used it for a project, you should have a pretty good idea how to use it on the next one, so I'm not sure what your confusion is. What is the new project and how is it different from the old one that it's causing you confusion. Please [edit] to add more details to help us help you better.

Comment: @FreeMan I did not use the material, contractors left it, so I’m not sure in what aspect they used the EasySand vs the premix buckets of Plus3. I had never heard of using EasySand for taping.

Comment: That would have been good into to share. Helps eliminate confusion.

Comment: Easy sand sounds like a topping or setting mud. They are vastly different. Setting mud or hot mud is a different type of mud that sets up in 15-90 minutes is is usually hard to sand. Topping mud is usually much softer than all purpose mud and for the second coat after taping because of its lighter density it drys faster but is very soft so it sands easy. So it matters what it actually is. I use setting mud in bathrooms and around sinks, I don’t know of any setting /hot mud that comes pre mixed only powder form. Both topping and general purpose mud come pre mixed and in powder form.

Answer (score 1):

Easy sand 45 is like a setting all purpose mud and can be used for taping. I'd personally use  thinned all purpose as it's easier to work with for taping and you don't have the same time constraints. A bag of easysand is like $10 so it's not that much of a waste. Use it to prefill joints or even nail holes but for taping it's not ideal ime

https://www.usg.com/content/dam/USG_Marketing_Communications/united_states/product_promotional_materials/finished_assets/sheetrock-lightweight-settingtype-joint-compounds-easy-sand-submittal-J621.pdf

Answer (score 0):

The initial 1-2 coats should be with All Purpose joint compound. It will set slower than fast set, but dries much harder, too. Use fast set on top if you need more coats.

Comment: Okay so I can use All Purpose for taping? Should I ever use EasySand for taping?

Comment: If easy sand is a topping mud it is not good for taping.

Comment: @EdBeal never heard of EasySand being a topping mud, it’s setting for prefill is it not?

Comment: There is an easy sand that is one of the topping muds I use, but after reading it may be a “hot mud” in your location I wanted to make the op aware there are large differences in topping and setting compounds.

Comment: @datta- a topping mud is a lighter-type of compound. As the name implies it is used after the tape and 1st or 2nd layer is applied. It's used to fill small voids and sands very easy.